# Contenteditable: remove formatting on text inside a tag node

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I'm developing a basic html editor inside a contenteditable div (the code is based on various solutions provided by the wizard of ranges [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down)).

It's working (it can insert html node replacing the selection of the user), but there's one main feature missing, if the user select a letter inside a tag (strong for example), he should be able to remove the formatting on that letter, so.

```
<strong>lorem ipsum</strong>
```

the user select the "i" of ipsum:

```
<strong>lorem |i|psum</strong>
```

when the user press the "Add/remove strong tag" button, the result should be:

```
<strong>lorem </strong>i<strong>psum</strong>
```

with the current code this is the result (which is fine for tags != strong):

```
<strong>lorem <strong>i</strong>psum</strong>
```

I need a snippet that is activated when the user select some text and press a button to insert/remove tags and follow these istructions:

- find the parent tag (if exists)
- if (new tag == parent tag) split the parent tag in 2 tags
- insert the (unformatted) selection between the 2 tags

This is a though one, I know...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's not too hard with straight DOM methods and properties. `splitText()`, `parentNode`, `tagName`, `insertBefore()`.

Comment: Although it's a harder problem if the selection boundaries are in different nodes.